# Explain mathematical practice and axiomatization to non-mathematicians

Tags: logic, education, philosophy, axioms, foundations

I am asked to give a talk about (a) mathematical practice, (b) axiomatization, (c) Gödel's theorems and (d) possible antimechanist arguments based on the incompleteness theorems (as mentioned in P Smith's Introduction to Gödel's theorems, 28.6., J Lucas or R Penrose) to non-mathematicians.

As all these points can not be explained in 1 hour, I need to cut it short while still being able to present a coherent talk. So I certainly will miss something out, the question is what. To transport the intuition/message I will probably even cite some things not completely correct.

For the first part (a),(b) of this 1 hour talk, I want to point out, what mathematical practice is, i.e., what mathematicians are doing, that they are not calculating anything aiming to explain the nature (that's the physicist's task). Raise the question why mathematics seems to reflect some natural aspects and allows application in nearly every field of science. Last but not least what it is about logic and axiomatization, which should be as complete and detailed enough to allow explaining Gödel on a more imprecise level.

I thought that due to the lack of time it would be helpful stating a toy example of an (very restricted) axiomatic system and to prove one simple statement. As I do not feel qualified to think of such an example myself I was looking for something similar around. Do you have any ideas?

Do you know illustrative examples or cartoons or analogies, which show what mathematicians are doing, that they actually just reconstruct tautologies or "unfold the axioms" since actually everything is already included in the axioms.

As I feel not that comfortable with such a talk, I would appreciate any helpful comments on how to organize that talk. How to intuitively but still precisely present a coherent talk which transports the most important points. I would like to clarify some views of mathematics (mathematics is not being an expert in doing calculations) and what is wrong about a philosopher rather uncautious citing Gödel as "we can not prove everything" — it seems popular to unknowingly cite Gödel as it is to cite quantum mechanics.

Comment: What do you think about the idea to quote Banach Tarski's paradoxon to expound the problems of "matheatics (tries to) explain(s) reality" and the self-evidence of axiomas or how the measured against our intuition or experience in the physical world?

Comment: My favourite proof for the non-math specialist is the one about the hiker from Martin Gardiner's "Gotcha." On one day, a hiker follows a path from his home in the village to his cabin in mountains and stays overnight. The following day, he returns home along the same path. You can "prove" that, on his return journey, he will be at the same point at exactly the same time of day as the previous day. Just imagine both journeys happening simultaneously. The hiker would have to run into his double at some point, as long as he doesn't deviate from the path. See humorous diagrams in the book.

Comment: I like Gardiner's hiker because it demonstrates, in a cartoon sort of way, what a proof is. Most people don't have a clue. They will see that you are not just calculating where and when -- what they think mathematicians do -- but you are showing that such a point must exist. You could also make a simple distance-time graph to up the level of abstraction just a bit.

Comment: I don't know if you could prove it easily, but the logical extension of this example could be demonstrated with 2 identical sheets of paper. Crumple one and it lay it in top on top of the other, without the crumpled piece extending past past the edge of the flat sheet. At least one point on the crumpled sheet will be exactly above the corresponding point on the flat sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible system that you might use for explaining a system of axioms without having to spend a huge amount of time might be Douglas Hofstadter's "MU" system.

The ideas are explained [here on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MU_puzzle), where it is described as a puzzle, but it could be presented as a system of axioms.

You are initially given a string "MI" and a number of rules (axioms) that allow you to create other strings:

1. Add a U to anything ending in I
2. Replace Mx by Mxx
3. Replace 3 consecutive Is with a U
4. Delete 2 consecutive Us

The aim is to produce MU given only the starting string MI.
It is actually impossible to do so.

Incidentally, if you have not read Hofstadter's book "[Gödel, Escher, Bach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach)", it might be worth looking into, as it is written for people without massive mathematical experience and does talk about axiomatic systems and Gödel's theorem(s).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It looks quite neat and shows the power of "mathematical reasoning". But e.g. Wikipedia's proof that _MI_ can not be turne to _MU_ is not a mathematical proof in the sense that it does not solve the problem by using the axioms but rather some "number theory".

Comment: Very true, but you could use the "axioms" inside the MU system to show how to prove a "theorem" such as "MUI" by using some of the axioms a few times - even ask the audience if they could see how to do it?    I would show them one or two such theorems, and then tell them (but not go through a proof) that obtaining MU is not possible - i.e. there are some strings which are not theorems.

Comment: That's true. Maybe the Wikipedia proof could even serve as an example of what is not a mathematical proof despite it seems so appealing to intuitive logic. Afterwards I could present or ask the adience for a proof of another theorem.

Comment: Yes, there are lots of possibilities - your main problems are likely to be "what will the audience cope with?" and "how much time can I spend on each bit of the talk?".

Comment: I think this example could be helpful for (b). I would need some easy but striking examples/arguments in what way mathematics is not what many people think. Following up, I need a good transition to prepare the basis for Goedel's theorems to allow following some antimechanical arguments. The final goal would be to enable the audience in a way to discuss these arguments. I am new to this forum: possibly I should post another question about the (c) and (d) parts, right?

Comment: I think the Wiki proof is valid, even though it doesnt appeal to the axioms of the system in question. Anyone care to disagree? :-)

Comment: It is not proven in the given axiomatic system. Rather some arguments appeal to axioms of other "systems"..

Comment: Is that necessarily a problem? Can you prove it in the given axiomatic system?

Comment: Doesn't the wiki proof compare to Gentzen's proof of GCH using methods outside the theory under consideration?

Comment: I see. So basically whether we can prove a result from some axioms is a different question (with possibly different answer) than if we can prove it using a different set of assumptions, right?

Comment: Has anyone given a mathematical proof of the impossibility? Is such a proof possible?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that the Wiki proof shows that no mathematical proof can be given?

Comment: Disclaimer: I am not an expert on that. I think it's better to say that the wiki proof compares to Gentzen's proof of GCH since it uses outside arguments. I guess the MI-MU problem is not an illustration of incompleteness theorem, since the MU system is not _powerful enough_ (it does not contain Robinson arithemtic) so the incompleteness theorem does not apply. Despite that, I do not know a "mathemtical" ("mathematical" meaning "staying within an axiomatic system") proof of the MU-MI problem within the MU system yet..

Comment: I am (obviously) also not an expert, but I feel that the Wiki proof more closely compares to Cohen´s proof of the undecidability of CH.

Comment: To put it differently: an "outside" proof (the wiki proof of the MU-MI problem or Genzent's proof of GCH) does not anyhow prove that no proof can be found within that system. Otherwise I just could just declare any theorem under consideration as an axiom and hence can give a trivial outside proof.

Comment: I guess I know what you are getting at, but I think that the wiki´s solution DOES show no proof can be given within the system. Afterall it shows you cannot derive the proposition MU given MI. What do you think?

Comment: And we can think of all such derivations as proofs in the system.

Comment: Ok, I thought a proof of the impossibilty of transforming MU into MI, as the wiki proof does. So whether this proof can be given within the MU system.

Comment: All proofs within the system are just sequences like MU, MUI,... so I do not think that THAT can give you any information about what can be proven in the system.???

Comment: Unless you enumerate all possible proofs and show that none of them leads from MI to MU...???

Comment: In case you are interested, I already have a resolution the statement that MU cannot be changed into MI not only cannot be proven within the system, it cannot be even stated in the system. (because the system doesnt have notions like "change")

Comment: Hm. I am confused now. How would you state any theorem in the MU system then? I think we are taking something wrong...anyone here to help? ;-)

Comment: I would say that anything that can be deduced from the starting string "MI" by using one of the 4 "axioms" could be called a "theorem" - e.g. MII, MIIII, MUI, MIU, ...

Comment: @AminCophag Adam is right.  If we think of Hofstadter's system as a system of formal logic then MI is the sole axiom, "add U to anything ending in I" _etc._ are deduction rules, and the question is whether MU is a theorem of the system.  The statement "MU is not a theorem of the system" can be shown to be true by an easy argument using arithmetic.  This statement is a _meta_-theorem:  a theorem _about_ the system, not a theorem _of_ the system.

Comment: @AminCophag ...here are some examples of other (trivial) meta-theorems: "MIU is a theorem of the system," "if xIIIIIIy is a theorem of the system, then so is xy."  To avoid confusion it is important to understand the separation between levels; _i.e._ between "reasoning" _in_ the system (by manipulating strings of M, I, and U according to the rules) and reasoning _about_ the system (using whatever tools, _e.g._ modular arithmetic, you see fit to apply, although if you wanted you could restrict the meta-theory to only allow certain tools.)

Comment: @AminCophag ...learning about Gödel's incompleteness theorems too soon can be confusing because one might then expect _all_ formal systems to be able to talk about their own provability.  Gödel showed that Peano Arithmetic has this very special property.  Hofstadter's system almost certainly does not (although I haven't thought about how to show this.)

Comment: @AminCophag ...and to answer your question about how I would state any theorem in Hofstadter's system: MIU.  There, I stated a theorem in Hofstadter's system.  To state _that_ MIU _is_ a theorem is a different statement---a statement in the meta-language.

Comment: @TrevorWilson: Thanks for your comments. I think the separation between "levels' is now clearer to me. But I do not see now, how one could argue, that the wiki proof, which is a meta proof, is actually 'correct' since we first would need to agree on whether we accept basic arithmetic for meta-reasoning. My picture somehow got cloudy ;-)

Comment: @AminCophag That is a good question.  My answer is that, depending on the situation, it may be okay to reason formally at the object level (_e.g._ in Hofstadter's system) but informally at the meta-level.  In practice it seems to usually be the case that all the arguments one wants to use at the meta-level can be formalized using Peano Arithmetic, because the arguments just deal with finite objects (formal proofs in the system) under finitary operations.  Because most people accept Peano Arithmetic as "true" it is often used informally without comment in this context.